# llvm pass error

Tags: llvm, clang, bytecode, frontend

i'm using this guide: http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html for creating an llvm pass, but i have the following error when i use

```
opt -load ../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello < hello.bc > /dev/null


Error opening '../../../Release/lib/Hello.so': ../../../Release/lib/Hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm12PassRegistry12registerPassERKNS_8PassInfoEb
  -load request ignored.
opt: Unknown command line argument '-hello'.  Try: 'opt -help'
```

note that i haven't the folder "Debug+Asserts" but "Release"

someone know what's the problem?

maybe because for creating the Hello.bc file i use llvm-clang instead of llvm-gcc? (this guide says to use llvm-gcc but it doesn'n work: http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#tutorial) or maybe because i have opt version 2.8 while i'm using llvm-3.0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the same version of `opt` as the LLVM version you're building the pass against.

Comment: ok, i solved all! :) ... i was still having llvm-2.9 and llvm-2.8 on my pc. now i have only the llvm-3.0, i recreate the .bc file and now it works! :) Thankyou

Comment: @Nicola: can't you "accept" it, though? [clicking on the V below the answer score]